# R: Using p.adjust to correct z-scores for multiple testing

Tags: r

I have a set of normal approximated `z-scores`, which I need to correct for multiple testing, I do this by converting the `z-score` to the corresponding adjusted `p-value`, as follows:

```
# Reproducible R-code
z      = -24.831
ntests = 487
p      = 2*pnorm(-abs(z))                  # Yields p = 4.14869e-136
p.adj  = p.adjust(p,method="fdr",n=ntests) # Yields p.adj = 2.020412e-133
z.adj  = qnorm(1-p.adj/2) * sign(z)        # Yields z.adj = -Inf
```

So I start with `z = -24.831` and after correction for multiple testing, I have `z = -Inf`. I have a system, where I need the actual corrected `z-scores` and the value `-Inf` does not "fit" in this system.

Can I get the actual value instead of just `-Inf` or is this a over/underflow issue?

Comment: I find this a strange notion. A z-score is not something that should be corrected for multiple testing.

Comment: @Roland : If you have system, in which you compute `n` normal approximated `z-scores`, each derived from one statistical test. Then each `z-score` can be converted to a `p-value` by standard method, yielding n `p-values` obtained by performing `n` tests. Then I wish to correct each `p-value` with `n` tests and convert back to `z-scores`. I do not se any problem in this. It is just a question of wanting to report the `p-values` or the `z-scores`? In this particular case, I want the `z-scores`.

Comment: z-scores are not derived from statistical tests. They are used for statistical tests. This is a fundamental misconception of statistical methodology on your part.

Comment: @Roland : Okay, allow me to rephrase. Let us say, that I have performed a set of `n` tests. The outcome of each test is a `score`. The distribution of these `scores` obtained from the `n` tests can be approximated by `N(0,1)`. Hence a `score` of `1.96` can be transformed to `p=0.05`. Let us say we performed `n=10` test, then the (bonferroni) corrected `p` is `0.50`. I then want to transform this value into standard score space. I.e. if I had a `p-value` of `0.50`, what would the corresponding standard score then by? I obtain the transformed value like so `qnorm(1-0.50/2)`, which equals `0.674`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I stay by my opinion that this doesn't make statistical sense, but you can change your last line of code to this:

```
z.adj  = qnorm(p.adj/2, lower.tail = FALSE) * sign(z)  
#[1] -24.58093
```

This avoids calculating `1 - p.adj/2` which due to floating point arithmetics (see `help(".Machine")`) is equal to 0.

Comment: Perfect - Thanks! Solved the problem `-qnorm(p.adj/2)` yields the same answer as `qnorm(1-p.adj/2)`, BUT is capable of handling very small values of `p.adj`!

Answer (score 1):

Elaborating on @Roland's answer and comment, what you want is unreasonable considering the meaning of the quantities you are using.

A z-score or other statistics resulting from statistical tests are transformations of some specific values (in the case of z-scores: `z=(x-mu)/sigma`). These are tied to those particular values and should not be corrected. However, when deciding whether a statistic has a value that would warrant rejecting a hypothesis, it is advisable to correct the calculated *probability* value when performing a large number of statistical tests, as you pointed out.

That being said (and to get more on-topic for SO), I also think this is reasonable behaviour to expect from `R`. For all intents and purposes, your `p.adj == 0`, which corresponds to `z = -Inf`. Even when achieving the correct result (as in Roland's answer), it is actually irrelevant, keeping in mind the intepretation of these values. In other words, probability of `10^-133` **is zero** and three orders of magnitudes do not make any difference. Even more so, when realizing these are numerical, rather than analytical, computations.

Comment: I see your points, however since `z~N(0,1)` can be transformed into a `p-value`, then we have `f(z)=p` and in my particular case I am interested in reporting `f(p)=z`. Since I have `sign(z)` available, we in essence have equivalent values! It is just a matter of reporting the values in `p` space or `z` space.

Comment: I would agree that there exists an isomorphism between `z` and `p` values (since `z` simply denotes the upper boundary of an integral in the definition of `p`), so they are equivalent in mathematical sense. However, when reporting on statistical quantities, I feel it is important to keep in mind their *statistical* interpretation, rather than just mathematical definition. These questions are what my observations address: is it sensible to distinguish such a low probability from zero and what the corrections actually mean. Reporting "corrected" `z-values` would obscure these issues.